# Chosen:Trigger function if no results

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm using Chosen jquery plugin. It shows "no results" if none found.
Is thera a way to trigger a function if no results found using this plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a developer of Chosen I can safely tell you that there is currently no callback or event triggered when there are no results.

Although you could submit a feature request as an issue at the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/issues/new?title=Feature%20request%3a%20Callback%20or%20event%20on%20no%20results)

The last few weeks there has been active development on Chosen, so changes of quick action upon your request are good.

Comment: I have checked there. THere is an open request for this feature
Link: https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/pull/166

Comment: That is my PR yes, but I thought that you were talking about just a simple event/callback, without the possibility of adding an option

Comment: Ultimately I want to achieve that. If i can trigger a function I can do what i want.

Comment: I have already implemented this solution but anyway thank you for your valuable help and since this answer is useful in getting solution of the actual problem so I am accepting it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Now, There is event **chosen:no_results** that you bind function to like this:

```
     $('select.chosen-select').bind('chosen:no_results', chosenNoResults);

    function chosenNoResults(evt, params) {
             //Add new Option Logic
     }
```

[image]

Refer [Github](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html#triggered-events) for Reference